# Space between two things on website

Tags: html, css, web, space, between

I'm kinda new to coding in html and css so I really need help. 
I was wondering how i could make space between two things 
like this: **http://prntscr.com/6vo7lz** 
in this **http://prntscr.com/6vo7x7**.

I really need help, if someone needs more information to solve the problem please just comment the question.

Thanks in advance.
Sorry for bad english, I'm swedish.

Comment: Your question is clearly unclear. What have you done what you did ? 
have a look on CSS properties : margin & padding

Comment: What exactly do you want space between? I didn't understand what elements you want to separate.

Comment: A relevant demo with your code in a fiddle is way too helpful than screenshots!

Answer (score 1):

From what I get from the two pictures you are trying to get `padding` in between to HTML elements. You can accomplish this easily by using CSS.

Try adding this to your CSS: `.header { padding-bottom:20px; }

This will tell all the HTML elements below it **to move 20px below it**.

Hope this helped!